# Rails - Relacionamento BD

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Tenho uma tabela `user`, onde tenho um campo obrigatório `cidade`, e tenho uma tabela `contatos` (que é `belongs_to: user`), porém no formulário não tem o campo `cidade` que é obrigatório para `user`. Como que eu faço para colocar o campo cidade sendo *optional no model* `contato`?

Fiz `belongs_to > optional: true` e não funcionou.

No models/user.rb estou fazendo essa validacao com `validate_presence_of`

Answer (score 1):

Tente desta forma:

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```